# ROS2 colcon build on windows no error message shown when it failed

Tags: ros, ros2, build, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to know what and where are the bugs  in my code,however, using the colcon build only show **failed** when there are something wrong.
I've tried **colcon --log-level debug build** or **colcon build --log-level info build** but still no error message shown
Is there any way to fix this out?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/322780/ros2-colcon-build--on-windows-no-error-message-shown-when-it-failed/) by [tingwei](https://answers.ros.org/users/34295/tingwei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2019-05-08

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately the Visual Studio compiler outputs error messages to `stdout` instead of `stderr`. By default `colcon build` hides the `stdout` output and only shows `stderr` output.

You can configure the output using the option `--event-handlers ...`. In this case you likely want to use `console_cohesion+` to enable always outputting all output after a package has been finished. Another option would be `console_direct+` but that would interleave the output from packages processed in parallel so only recommended when you build a single package.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2019-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tingwei](https://answers.ros.org/users/34295/tingwei/) on 2019-05-08**:
thanks a lot ,it do work  by using colcon build --event-handlers console_cohesion+